# TweePy For Loop not looping all data

Tags: python, for-loop, tweepy

Use this is code snippet :

```
user = api.get_user('xxxx')
print(user.followers_count)
for i in user.friends():
    print(i.screen_name)
```

result for follower count is 700
but why when looping all data only show 21 row data?

Answer (score 0):

Whilst getting the names of all followers of a user is possible you are likely to get banned from exceeding rate limits quickly.

The following code will tell you how many followers a user has and then list all the username of the people who follow the user.

```
username = 'keely_bro'
userID = api.get_user(username)
print('User is followed by ' + str(userID.followers_count) + ' people')
print('usernames of followers: ')
for allFollowers in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers_ids, screen_name=username).pages():
    followerNames = [userID.screen_name for userID in api.lookup_users(allFollowers)]
    for follow in followerNames:
        print(follow)
```